# Is there a way to make OnNodeSelect not expand or collapse for material ui treeview

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui treeview and I dont really understand the difference between OnNodeSelect vs OnNodeToggle they seem to be doing the same thing since OnNodeSelect makes the treeview expand/collapse I was wondering if there was a way to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `onNodeSelect` is fired whenever a node is selected, but `onNodeToggle` is fired when a node that has children nodes is toggled.
I hope that makes sense to you